# Chain Observable with HttpClient post

Tags: typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I'm a quite newbie to TypeScript (or even JavaScript) and Angular 6. I have to retrieve an observable value, pass it to `HttpClient.post` and process the response.

Somehow I'm not able to do it correctly. The following does not compile, since return is here `Observable<Observable<string>>`. But how do I it correctly?

```
refreshTokenCall: Observable<string> = null;

refreshToken(): Observable<string> {

  if (!this.refreshTokenCall) {

    // Here is the error: Type 'Observable<Observable<string>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
    // Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'. [2322]

    this.refreshTokenCall = this.getToken().pipe(
      map(token => {
        console.log("try refresh")
        return this.http.post<Token>(AuthService.REFRESH_TOKEN_URL, JSON.stringify({token: token})).pipe(
          map(data => data.token),
          shareReplay(),
          tap(token => { 
            console.log("save token after refresh");
            this.saveToken(token);
          }),
          finalize(() => this.refreshTokenCall = null)
        );
      })
    );

  } // if
  return this.refreshTokenCall;
```

I tried to put the second map `map(data => data.token)` into the first `pipe` but then the argument `data`is of type `Observable<Token>`. At least what syntactically works is to replace the first `map`by `switchMap`. I think then I have my problems with the [documentation about `switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)

> switchMap stops emitting items from the earlier-emitted inner Observable and begins emitting items from the new one.

I hope the `if` condition catches all subsequent calls. But somehow my Observable pipeline is not processed. The log entries do not appear.

So what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think switchMap is the way to go, not sure what issue you have with that. I know the documentation is confusing, but it's because Observables are so flexible and the documentation has to explain every scenario. You don't have to understand that part right now

Comment: thanks, I will check the direction.